# anaconda installing numpy/pandas/matplotlib error

Tags: numpy, anaconda

first post here, so I'm going to try to be as thorough as possible.

I'm trying to install numpy/matplotlib/pandas for a project. First time trying to use them. I'm following the steps of a tutorial, so I can't vary from that too much (have to use anaconda). I'm using mac OS Sierra 10.12.5

What I've done: 
installed python 3, anaconda, and create and initialize a virtual environment using Anaconda. I then type:

conda install numpy pandas matplotlib

The terminal then tells me what new packages will be installed, I proceed. A few are installed successfully, and then I get this error:

CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/mkl-2017.0.3-0.tar.bz2
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

I thought this might be a connection issue, as I'm in China, but I've tried multiple times both using and not using a VPN. This problem is really stopping me in my tracks, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the pip installer, or installing using the Anaconda navigator? To install using pip, after creating the virtual environment, open a terminal console, and type

```
source activate [name of virtual environment]
pip install numpy
pip install matplotlib
pip install pandas
```

Pip is included in the base anaconda installation, so this should work. If your Anaconda installation included the Anaconda Navigator, you can also install these modules through the GUI, by opening the Anaconda Navigator, clicking on the environments tab, selecting the virtual environment, searching for module in the search bar (make sure you select All and not Installed in the dropdown menu next to it), and then selecting the desired modules and clicking the apply button ([this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXjlF.png) is an example).

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for that answer. I'm not very computer literate so I have to clarify, do these two commands do the same thing? "pip install pandas" and " conda install pandas" ? Because when I pip install like you suggested, I'm told the requirement is already satisfied, but when I try to conda install an installation process starts that is extremely slow and ends in an error.

Comment: pip install numpy pandas matplotlib seems to be working. You are a wise and powerful sage. Thanks